# Store multiple links in one Firefox bookmark

Tags: firefox, bookmarks

Is it possible to store multiple links under one bookmark and put it at my *Bookmarks Toolbar*, so the links under it will open simultaneously in their respective tabs each time I click it?

Examples:

- I visit several Stack Exchange sites and I want to store them all under one bookmark to open them easily and check what's new.
- I participating in several forums and I want to open their *new posts* pages at once.

The workaround I found so far is to create a folder for each group I want and click the *Open All in Tabs* item at the bottom of it. I am seeking something more elegant and faster than opening menu and selecting an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store all your bookmarks in one folder then simply Middle Click (or Control-click if your on a laptop). This opens all of the links in the folder at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [LinkBunch](http://linkbun.ch/) to put multiple links into one small link. Then you can save this small link as a bookmark. When you click on "Open entire bunch" in the coming page, all your links will be opened.

Comment: Somehow this requires more steps than my workaround I am afraid, as I am required to first open a web page and then click a link instead of opening a menu and clicking an option.